# Maven install plugin with depedency packaging

Tags: maven

I have Project A and Project B. ProjectB just has only proprietary jars or third party libs that ProjectA needs which cannot be found in maven repository. I intended to package all the related ( grouping dependencies) jars of Project B into one/more jar files. Question is, how do I install these jars and shade/assemble them in to one jar  at the same time using POM. I  am getting proprietary jars installed separately but I cannot get them packaged them in to one jar. M2 eclipse is also not helping much , so I decide to use mvn commands inside eclipse. What is the best practice to do this?. I think shading them since I want to use these dependencies in other projects as well.Can I install and shade/assemble jars(  logically group the related dependencies in to one jar) at the time using POM?.

I followed this( from stack over flow forum) , it did not work- as this is creating one project jar which doesn't have anything + proprietary jars separately but not shading all jars in to one. I want them installed and combined in to one jar at the same time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.projectdeps</groupId>
    <artifactId>sharedlibs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>shared-libs</name>

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install activationjar</id>
                        <goals><goal>install-file</goal></goals>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>

               <file>${basedir}/src/main/libs/activation.jar</file>
                            <groupId>com.mycompany.activation</groupId>
                            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                            <version>12.8</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
         <execution>
                        <id>install opsjar</id>
                        <goals><goal>install-file</goal></goals>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>

               <file>${basedir}/src/main/libs/Operations.jar</file>
                            <groupId>com.mycompany.gcs.ops</groupId>
                            <artifactId>Operations</artifactId>
                            <version>12.8</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <filters>
              <filter>
                <artifact>Operations</artifact>
                <includes>
                  <include>/**</include>

                </includes>
              </filter>
            </filters>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
      <dependencies>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Why is it important to combine all the dependent JARs into a single JAR?